# Getting specific errors when TCP connections disconnect in Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to improve the usefulness of the error reporting in a server I am working on.  The server uses TCP sockets, and it runs on Windows.

The problem is that when a TCP link drops due to some sort of network failure, the error code that I can get from WSARecv() (or the other Windows socket APIs) is not very descriptive.  For most network hiccups, I get either WSAECONNRESET (10054) or WSAETIMEDOUT (10060).  But there are about a million things that can cause both of these: the local machine is having a problem, the remote machine or process is having a problem, some intermediate router has a problem, etc.  This is a problem because the server operator doesn't have a definitive way to investigate the problem, because they don't necessarily even know where the problem is, or who might be responsible.

At the IP level, it's a different story.  If the server operator happens to have a network sniffer attached when something bad happens, it's usually pretty easy to sort of what went wrong.  For instance, if an intermediate router sent an ICMP unreachable, the router that sent it will put its IP address in there, and that's usually enough to track it down.  Put another way, Windows killed the connection for a reason, probably because it got a specific packet that had a specific problem.

However, a large number of failures are experienced in the field, unexpected.  It is not realistic to always have a network sniffer attached to a production server.  There needs to be a way to track down problems that happen only rarely, intermittently, or randomly.

How can I solve this problem programmatically?

Is there a way to get Windows to cough up a more specific error message?  Is there some easy way to capture and mine recent Windows events (perhaps the one Microsoft Network Monitor uses)?  One way I've "solved it" before is to keep dumpcap (from Wireshark) running in ring buffer mode, and force it to stop capturing when a bad event happens, that I can mine later.

I'm also open to the possibility that this is not the right way to solve this problem.  For instance, perhaps there is some special Windows mode that can be turned on to cause it to log useful information, that a network administrator could use to track this down after-the-fact.

Comment: The localhost can't distinguish most of those cases. It can't distinguish between a router failure and a remote target failure for example.

Comment: It can distinguish in most important cases.  If you set aside TCP timeout and related issues (which generally require some active troubleshooting), the disconnect is going to be caused by a specific host sending a packet that causes Windows to drop the connection.  Whether it's the TCP protocol, ICMP protocol, or link layer, in almost all cases, the host sending the error packet identifies itself.  It is fair to say I am much more concerned with brief transient outages, than long-lasting ones that cause timeouts, because long-lasting ones last long enough for a human to troubleshoot.